# Why does text in Div center in Dreamweaver, but not on web?

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me why the URLS at the bottom of this page aren't centering? I have set the CSS to center div#urls with margin: 50px auto;

```
<style>
    div#container {
        padding: 0px;
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    h1 {
        font:Cambria;
        font-size:15px;
        width: 100%;
        textalign: left;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    div#urls {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 50px auto;
        textalign: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>The information</h1>
        <div id="urls">
            <a href="index.htm">HOME</a> | <a href="about.htm">ABOUT</a> | <a href="contact.htm">CONTACT</a> | <a href="privacy">PRIVACY</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property is called `text-align`, not `textalign` and Dreamweaver's so-called-WYSIWYG view is dreadful.

(NB: if you have a list of links, then you should [mark them up as a list](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/), and draw borders between them using the CSS `border` property and not ASCII art `|` characters)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your css, it should be text-align with dash in the middle